# Summing edges in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Have a dataframe that represents a network with directed edges between nodes A, B and C. I want to sum the flows between nodes to measure the strength of connections between nodes. Below is the df I have..

```
To  From Flow
A   A   1
A   B   4
A   C   2
B   A   5
B   B   2
B   C   6
C   A   3
C   B   5
C   C   2
```

And the below is what I'd like to get to.

```
A   A   1
B   B   2
C   C   2
A   B   9
A   C   5
B   C   11
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve this.

```
df["Node 1"] = df[["To","From"]].min(axis=1)
df["Node 2"] = df[["To","From"]].max(axis=1)
result = df.groupby(["Node 1","Node 2"], as_index=False)["Flow"].sum()
```

The first two lines just create a consistent order for the groups. The third line just adds up the groups now that there is a consistent grouping.

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth, I tried two slightly different approaches:

1.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data={"To": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"],
                          "From": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"],
                          "Flow": [1, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3, 5, 2]})

data[["To", "From"]] = data[["To", "From"]].apply(sorted, axis=1)
data.groupby(by=["To", "From"], as_index=False).sum()
```

2.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data={"To": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"],
                          "From": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"],
                          "Flow": [1, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3, 5, 2]})

swap = data.To < data.From
data.loc[swap, ["To", "From"]] = data.loc[swap, ["From", "To"]].values
data.groupby(by=["From", "To"], as_index=False).sum()
```

And both perform much worse than Gabriel A's solution, which is very good :)

Comment: In Pandas the fastest solution usually involves using the built in vectorized functions. Your first code is a more natural way of sorting each row but apply is slow :/